# How to verify date input into 3 separate fields?

Tags: javascript, date

I have three fields for date input - day, month, year.
Once it is input, I should verify it. The following code is used:

```
$('#test').click(function(event) {
    var daySelector = "#dd",
        monthSelector = "#mm",
        yearSelector = "#yyyy";
    var day = $(daySelector).val() == "" ? 1 : parseInt($(daySelector).val(), 10);
    var month = $(monthSelector).val() == "" ? 1 : parseInt($(monthSelector).val(), 10);
    var year = parseInt($(yearSelector).val(), 10);
    var date = new Date(year, month, day);
    var result = !isNaN(date.getTime());    
});
```

But it accepts (i.e. returns `true`) wrong values like 33/55/2000. Where is my mistake?
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/43BpT/1/)

I've tried [another approach](http://jsfiddle.net/43BpT/3/) - it doesn't work well also.

Comment: You can use || instead of the ternary operator for default values when null or empty.. x = x || 1.. not your answer, but easier to read

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876448/javascript-month-and-day-and-year-check

Comment: Any chance you could use a calendar or some other single field lookup? User experience for 3 separate date fields leaves something to be desired.

Comment: yes, and you won't need to worry about invalid input if you use something like jquery ui datepicker for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date object automaticly converts overflows.

So if you create 32.01.2000 and there are only 31 days in the january then it will create object with
01.02.2000 Date

You have to change your validation logic from "Is Nan" to something more sophisticated;)

One thing to note :)

date.getMonth() returns 0-11 -> 0 equals january :P That was the source of my initial mistake in the answer.
And it seems like you have to decrement value sent to the Date constructor.

Comment: interesting.. did not know that.

Comment: @PatrickScott me too but i tried different values and it seems that it works like that :O Just try it in the jsfiddle provided with question

Comment: And it seems that i am wrong beacuse there were 31 days in january 2000 :O

Comment: @michal  what you said is correct but what you type is wrong i hope   :-) jan have 31 .. your example should be for feb and march

Comment: yes, date.getTime() will always be a number because of the overflow conversion, so it will bever be NaN

Comment: Thanks, Michal. Second approach (with month value corrected - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/43BpT/7/) works well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider existing solutions:

- https://github.com/JerrySievert/node-date-utils
- http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/javascript-date-object/

=========

**UPD** Just pulled out function from one of these frameworks:

```
validateDay = function (day, year, month) {
    var date = new Date(year, month, day);
    return (date.getFullYear() === year &&
        date.getMonth() === month &&
        date.getDate() === day);
};​
```

Comment: Re your update - see the end of my question, I've mentioned there another approach - this is equal to what you've given. And it doesn't work, date 30-feb-2000 is treated as valid.

Comment: @LA_ maybe you've forgotten that month index starts whith 0. So January=0, February=1 (**not 2**) check this out again **it works** fine

Comment: Thanks. For month index issue, I use the following:

function ValidateDate(day, month, year) {
    var date = new Date(year, month-1, day);
    return (date.getFullYear() === year &&
        date.getMonth() === month-1 &&
        date.getDate() === day);
};